# Upgrade springboot version from 2.4.7 to 2.6.3 on a project generated by JHipster

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, jhipster

I have generated a project using jHipster 7.1.0 which created an application (monolith) without client for me using springboot version 2.4.7

With recent times after release of new versions of spring I would like to upgrade and fix dependencies of spring to 2.6.3

Even though I update the `springVersion` in `pom.xml` I don't see the change of version when I start the project. Any information will be of great help.

Comment: First, there is no such `springVersion` property in `pom.xml`, it's `spring-boot.version.` Check with `mvnw dependency:tree` to see resolved versions.

Answer (score 0):

You should check jhipster-dependencies and upgrade it ! The spring boot version comes with this dépendancy.

```html
implementation platform("tech.jhipster:jhipster-dependencies:${jhipster_dependencies_version}" )
```

Comment: Thanks @sizrandanes for the response. I will check and let accept the answer.